# PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid not readable (yet?) after start

Tags: zabbix

when i try to start the zabbix-server i am getting and run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid not readable (yet?) error,

```
ls -al

-rw-rw-r--.  1 zabbix zabbix   5 May  1 15:15 zabbix_server.pid
```

my zabbix-server config file

```
#This is a configuration file for Zabbix Server process
# To get more information about Zabbix,
# visit http://www.zabbix.com

############ GENERAL PARAMETERS #################

LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
LogFileSize=0
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid
#PidFile=/tmp/zabbix_server.pid
DBHost=localhost
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=zabbix
DBSocket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Please help. suggest me a solution

Comment: What are the permissions on the zabbix directory?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root       43 May  2 11:23 zabbix
[ec2-user@ip-10-100-140-9 ~]$ ls -al /etc/zabbix/
-rw---x---.  1 root   root    402 May  2 11:23 zabbix_server.conf

Answer (score 2):

That message only indicates that the server failed to start. Check the server log (`/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log` according to your config file), it will contain a more meaningful error message.

In my case, it was a issue connecting with the database.

Answer (score 1):

close the selinux on centos7
It works for me.

just close selinux for this time
`setenforce 0`

Close selinux forever
`vi /etc/selinux/config`
`SELINUX=disabled`

Comment: and a reboot you need.

Comment: If you have additional comments to make you can edit your post to include them.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue when building a zabbix 4.0 server. To fix the issue I made sure that the path to the PID file was correct on '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' and '/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-server.service'.

Interestingly restarting the service alone did not get rid of the error. I needed to reboot the server and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove current pid file + be sure that no *zabbix_server* process is running on your machine.

Comment: I did delete the file and killed the process, but i am still getting the same error. do you think its no able to read the file? I changed the permissions to 775 /var/run/zabbix/ it did not work , should i change the permissions of some other file?

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix server **does not accept special chars** like:  !@#$%^&*()_+,./;'[]}{|":?>< in DBPassword variable.

Comment: Please don't link to unnecessary websites like that, it will be treated as spam if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

check `/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log`
my problem was AllowUnsupportedDBVersions=1 in config zabbix

```
Unable to start Zabbix server due to unsupported PostgreSQL database version (12.18).
Must be at least (13.0).
Use of supported database version is highly recommended.
Override by setting AllowUnsupportedDBVersions=1 in Zabbix server configuration file at your own risk.
```